# python webhdfs kerberos not working

Tags: python, webhdfs

I need help , I am using webhdfs (also using this python code to call hadoop commands https://gist.github.com/drelu/1529478). For my system it is kerberized using KDC. I am able to do curl, but i don't know how to use this curl command in the above python code. Appreciate your help. My curl command is like below :

curl --cacert /opt/cloudera/security/CAcerts/rootc.cer --negotiate -u https://localhost:140000/webhdfs/v1/?op=liststatus

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this

> 1. With pywebhdfs python client https://github.com/pywebhdfs/pywebhdfs/issues/16#issuecomment-243776503
> 2. Without pywebhdfs directly calling the webhdfs REST calls
>      Example code: https://plenium.wordpress.com/2018/07/26/run-a-python-program-to-access-hadoop-with-kerberos-enabled/

On both the methods you need to create the authentication header using requests_kerberos module https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos#requests-kerberosgssapi-authentication-library

> 3. hdfscli python module can be used
>      https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In all the cases kinit need to be done manually (you can use some python shell executor modules like subprocess, commands .. to automate that also)